# What type of variable am I dealing with?

Tags: interaction, mediation, confounding

I'm researching the relationship between Gender and environmental voting behaviours in the USA, specifically looking at the environmental voting behaviours of members of Congress This is measured using the LCV environmental scorecard. scorecard.lcv.org/scorecard

Gender has been found to have an effect on environmental voting behaviours – men are more likely to have poorer environmental voting patterns than women. Political ideology has a stronger effect on environmental voting behaviours – a more conservative ideology corresponds with poorer voting behaviours. Additionally, gender was found to affect political ideology, men are more likely to be conservative than women.

What type of relationship is this? Is political ideology a mediating or confounding variable? 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you define *environmental voting behaviours*?

Comment: I'm specifically looking at the environmental voting behaviours of members of Congress This is measured using the LCV environmental scorecard. https://scorecard.lcv.org/scorecard

Comment: Please add new info that as an edit to the post! Not everybody reads comments ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Political ideology would be a mediator here if changes in political ideology caused changes in environmental voting patters. A mediator is a variable that falls on the causal path between two variables, caused by one and causing the other. If political ideology is a mediator, gender may be a confounder of the relationship between political ideology. A confounder is a variable that causes both a cause and its consequence. There may be other confounders of the relationship between political ideology and environmental voting patterns (e.g., age, religiosity, education, parents' attitudes), so simply observing an association between the two is not enough to make a causal claim.

Comment: Thank you! I basically ran a regression with environmental voting behaviours (I used a well-cited measure of this) as the DV, against gender, age, religion, profession, race, and a couple other variables to do with voting. When I ran the regression with political ideology, gender wasn't significant, however I ran a separate regression with political ideology as the DV and in this gender was highly significant.

Comment: When I swapped political ideology out for party preference, gender was significant in addition to party. I've also found research that suggests political ideology in the USA is strongly influenced by political ideology - joining one party and associating with member of the party often has the effect of shaping ideology to fit the party preferences.

Comment: I've just been struggling to figure out what is influencing what!

Comment: Super informative thanks, this was a useful example of confounding variables